# NSDictionary with custom keys behaves strangely - values sporadically changing to null and back

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, null

I'm having an issue with an `NSMutableDictionary` which I'm filling via a loop using a custom object type for the keys.  I've implemented `NSCopying` so I'd expect all to be ok.  Watching the results of the loop, I notice that the keys seem ok but the values are flipping  in and out of NULL very strangely.  Console output of the dictionary on each iteration:

```
{
    "C#-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4ba470>";
    "D-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4b5600>";
    "C-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0x1277f810>";
}
// ...ok so far

{
    "C#-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4ba470>";
    "C-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0x1277f810>";
    "D#-10" = (null);
    "D-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4b5600>";
}
// ...oops a null

{
    "C#-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4ba470>";
    "C-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0x1277f810>";
    "D#-10" = (null);
    "D-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4b5600>";
    "E-10" = (null);
}
// ...and another

{
    "C#-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4ba470>";
    "C-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0x1277f810>";
    "D#-10" = (null);
    "F-10" = (null);
    "D-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0xc4b5600>";
    "E-10" = "<SWPP_BeamModel: 0x1277fad0>";
}
// ...another but value for key "E-10" is back!
```

And it continues this way.  The final clincher is this line...

```
// De-mutablise
_noteBeamsMap = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:beamsMap];
```

Which results in a `_noteBeamsMap` of

```
{
    "D#9" = (null);
    G1 = (null);
    C14 = (null);
    "G-7" = (null);
    ...
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had implemented `isEqual:` in the the custom key class but not `hash` to match.  As put very concisely [in this helpful blog post](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=73) `hash` needs to return the same value whenever `isEqual:` returns YES.